# how to add class and remove class of list item

Tags: php

how to add class and remove class of list item. while i have a sidebar where i have conditioned that when normal users log in then this list will be displayed and if admin is logged in then another list will be displayed but all the list have single ul

for example :

```
session_start();
echo '<ul>';
switch($_SESSION['role'])
{
case 'admin':
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href="admin.php">Dashboard</a>';
 echo '</li>';
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href="manage.php">Manage User</a>';
 echo '</li>';
break;
case 'user':
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href="profile.php">Profile</a>'; 
 echo '</li>';
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href="status.php">Status</a>';
 echo '</li>'; 
break;
default:
break;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

So I want to say, when admin logged in then Dashboard and Manage User menu will show and so on.
if admin click on Manage User, its look should be changed through css for active class.

Please provide me solution.

Comment: That seems PHP, not jQuery.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: I want to add class for selected menu, so that it look like bold or in another styling. class might be active. I am using jquery for this which is. 
$('li').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});

@Oriol

Comment: Please update your question. That's not what it looked like you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should put an id to your menu to avoid confusion :

```
<ul id="menu">
```

You can do something like this :

```
$("#menu li").click(function () {
    $("#menu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```